# BrowserTest gives wrong connection

Tags: 8, database, testing

I am running a test that extends a BrowserTestBase and indicated a custom module as a dependency. The module has a `mymodule_module_preinstal()` that is supposed to perform a DB query using `Drupal::database()`.

After wasting some time on figuring out why it does not work I realized that the query is run against the main databse of the installation, not that which I had set up in phpunit.xml.

That's really confusing - why is it working like that and why on earth would I want to work with the main database while running a test which is supposed to be run in an isolated database?

And, most importantly, how do I run the query against the test database?

Excerpt from documentation:

> It's terribly important to realize that each test runs in a completely new Drupal instance, which is created from scratch for the test. In other words, none of your configuration and none of your users exists!

Here's code of my test:

```
class FormTest extends BrowserTestBase
{
    public static $modules = ['mymodule', 'mymodule2'];

    public function testFormPage()
    {
        $response = $this->drupalGet('/mymodule/register');
    }
}
```

I've also copied phpunit.xml.dist to phpunit.xml and set up this line:

```
<env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="mysql://mydb_tests:password@localhost/mydb_tests"/>
```

I run my test like this:

```
cd core
phpunit ../modules/mymodule/tests/src/MyTest.php
```

I have installed the version of phpunit from core/composer.json globally.

The preinstall hook looks like this:

```
/**
 * Module preinstall hook
 * @param $module_name
 */
function mymodule_module_preinstall($module_name)
{
    var_dump($module_name);

    print_r(Drupal::database()->query("SHOW TABLES")->fetchAll());
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Can you share your preinstall and also at least the set up method of your test?

Comment: Specifically, are you calling parent::setUp() and are you calling it *first*? Otherwise your code simply runs, setUp() is where all the work happens to install and create your isolated environment.

Comment: I have added the above details to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm, I don't override setUp at all as I rely on the module installer to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Show tables doesn't work like that. I doesn't know anything about prefixes, it lists all tables in the database.

The schema API has an API method to list tables, which is DB agnostic and respects the prefix.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean it doesn't work like that? It does work and returns me a list of tables from my main drupal database. The point being `Drupal::database()` returns a connection to my site's database, not test database. Looking at errors I got executing other queries, this same connection is used for the test, which is wrong.

Comment: Yes, it lists tables. All of them, including those with prefixes.

Comment: If you could tell me what is this API method to list tables I could test that to prove it's still using wrong onnection (or prove me wrong). Drupal's documentation is useless for looking this up.

Comment: Maybe your problem is running tests in the UI or run-tests.sh. If you want it to respect the phpunit configuration, you need to run them with phpunit. run-tests.sh uses a database table prefix. Always wrap all your tables with {} to make sure that they work then.

Comment: What I mean is Database::getConnection()->schema()->findTables('%');

Comment: I have amended the question to reflect that I run my test like this:
`phpunit ../modules/mymodule/tests/src/MyTest.php`

Comment: Also, having this in my phpunit.xml `<env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="mysql://mydb_tests:password@localhost/mydb_tests"/>` I expect the test to use it's own database `mydb_tests` as per https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/phpunit/running-phpunit-tests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46889/discussion-between-okneloper-and-berdir).